# why my recyclerView isn't being inflated?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

so i have a recyclerView which contains within it another recyclerView.
for some odd reason the main recyclerView isn't being inflated which means the inner one won't be inflated as well, i tried to find the problem for over 3 days now, but i still can't figure out what's the problem.[here is what the end result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh0ge.png)

here is a copy of my code:
the main fragment :

```
public class MainScreen extends Fragment {
private Dialog dialog;
private SchoolViewModel viewModel;
private PaymentsByDateParentAdapter adapter;
private FloatingActionMenu floatingActionMenu,floatingActionMenuList;
private FloatingActionButton addSubject,addTeacher,addPayment;
private FloatingActionButton subjectList,TeacherList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_screen, container, false);

    floatingActionMenu = v.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_menu);
    floatingActionMenuList = v.findViewById(R.id.fab_list_menu);
    addSubject = v.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_subject);
    addTeacher = v.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_teacher);
    addPayment = v.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_payment);
    subjectList = v.findViewById(R.id.fab_list_subject);
    TeacherList = v.findViewById(R.id.fab_list_teacher);
    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.rv_main_screen);


    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SchoolViewModel.class);
    List<PaymentByDate> paymentByDateList = new ArrayList<>();
    viewModel.getAllPayments().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Payment>>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Payment> payments) {
            List<String> datesWithDupes = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Payment i : payments){
                datesWithDupes.add(new String(i.getPaymentDate()));
            }
            List<String> datesWithoutDupes = datesWithDupes.stream()
                    .distinct()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            for (String date : datesWithoutDupes) {
                viewModel.getPaymentsByDate(date).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Payment>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(List<Payment> payments) {
                        paymentByDateList.add(new PaymentByDate(date,payments));
                    }
                });
                v.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),paymentByDateList.size()+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });




    adapter = new PaymentsByDateParentAdapter(paymentByDateList,getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    addSubject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openDialog();
            floatingActionMenu.close(true);
        }
    });
    addTeacher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(),R.id.nav_host).navigate(R.id.action_mainScreen_to_addTeacher);
            floatingActionMenu.close(true);
        }
    });
    addPayment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(),R.id.nav_host).navigate(R.id.action_mainScreen_to_add_payment_fragment);
            floatingActionMenu.close(true);
        }
    });
    subjectList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(),R.id.nav_host).navigate(R.id.action_mainScreen_to_subjecstListFragment);
            floatingActionMenuList.close(true);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

private void openDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_subject);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    Button confirmSubject = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm_subject);
    Button cancelSubject = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cacnel_subject);
    EditText etSubject = dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_add_subject);

    confirmSubject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String subjectName = etSubject.getText().toString();
            if (!subjectName.isEmpty()) {
                viewModel.addSubject(new Subject(subjectName));
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "confirm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    cancelSubject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });


    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    dialog.show();
}
```

the parent adapter class :

```
public class PaymentsByDateParentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PaymentsByDateParentAdapter.PaymentsByDateParentHolder> {
private List<PaymentByDate> paymentByDateList;
private Context context;

public PaymentsByDateParentAdapter(List<PaymentByDate> paymentByDateList, Context context) {
    this.paymentByDateList = paymentByDateList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public PaymentsByDateParentHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.date_row,parent,false);
    return new PaymentsByDateParentHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PaymentsByDateParentHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.dateTV.setText(paymentByDateList.get(position).getDate());
    holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new PaymentsByDateChildAdapter(paymentByDateList.get(position).getPayments()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return paymentByDateList.size();
}

protected class PaymentsByDateParentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView dateTV;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public PaymentsByDateParentHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        dateTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_payments_by_date);
    }
}
```

}

the child adapter class :

```
public class PaymentsByDateChildAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PaymentsByDateChildAdapter.PaymentsByDateChildHolder> {
private List<Payment> payments;

public PaymentsByDateChildAdapter(List<Payment> payments) {
    this.payments = payments;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public PaymentsByDateChildHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.payments_row,parent,false);
    return new PaymentsByDateChildHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PaymentsByDateChildHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.hoursTeached.setText(payments.get(position).getHoursTeached());
    holder.total.setText(payments.get(position).getPaymentTotal());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return payments.size();
}

public class PaymentsByDateChildHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView teacherName,hoursTeached,total;
    public PaymentsByDateChildHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        teacherName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teacher_name);
        hoursTeached = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_hours_teached);
        total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
    }
}
```

}

here is the xml file for the mainScreen :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_main_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fab_add_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:menu_colorNormal="#0029FF"
    app:menu_colorPressed="#94A5FF">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_subject_icon"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#0029FF"
        app:fab_colorPressed="#94A5FF"
        app:fab_label="add a subject"
        app:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_teacher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_teacher_icon"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#0029FF"
        app:fab_colorPressed="#94A5FF"
        app:fab_label="add a teacher"
        app:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_payment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_payment_icon"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#0029FF"
        app:fab_colorPressed="#94A5FF"
        app:fab_label="add a payment"
        app:fab_size="mini" />
</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fab_list_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    app:menu_labels_position="right"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu_colorNormal="#05FF00"
    app:menu_colorPressed="#58FF55">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_list_subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_subject_icon"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#05FF00"
        app:fab_colorPressed="#58FF55"
        app:fab_label="add a subject"
        app:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_list_teacher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_teacher_icon"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#05FF00"
        app:fab_colorPressed="#58FF55"
        app:fab_label="add a teacher"
        app:fab_size="mini" />

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and the xml file for the parent adapter :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:text="6 mars 2022"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:fontFamily="@font/k2d_semibold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_payments_by_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_date" />
```

and here is the xml code for the child adapter :

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#a0a0a0"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_teacher_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Prof Raouf Mesran"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/k2d_semibold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_hours_teached"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:text="3 Heurs"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/k2d_semibold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3600 DA"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/k2d_semibold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_teacher_name" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

if anyone can figure out why am unable to inflate it please let me know.
PS: if any extra code is needed please let me know

Comment: How do you know it isn't inflated? Was there any error? How does the UI look now? And if we're speaking about UI, you should probably post the XMLs of the related views. Please update the question because it might not be entirelly clear what the problem is here.

Comment: @sweak first it's not inflated because i created a button to check if the list passed to the adapter is actually populated, and it was indeed populated, so if the data are being passed successfully it means that the recyclerView layout isn't being inflated if am not mistaken, and no there was no errors (0 crashes), and the layout looks exactly like the prototype i linked before only without the list of dates as well as the list of payments for each day(it's blank) ,and i have updated to question to include the xml file to the main screen as well as the 2 adapters.